# Difficulty for using ArrayPad with Matrix

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a matrix M which is 4x4.

How can i create a 7x7 matrix with :

- the 2 first lines are 0
- the 2 first columns are 0
- the last lines is 0
- the last column is 0.

For the moment, I can do it like this:

```
M1 = ArrayPad[M, {{2, 0}, {2, 0}}]
M2 = ArrayPad[M1, {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

But I didn't understand the help on the function `ArrayPad` when they said "pads $m_i$, $n_i$ at level *i* in array"

Is it possible to obtain the 7x7 matrix I need directly through a single application of `ArrayPad`?

Comment: Did you try `ArrayPad[M, {2, 1}]` ?